# Python multiprocessing with a while loop and shared resources

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm new to programming and i cant seem to figure out how to correctly optimise my project, i have a function which takes 2 images and used opencv to stitch the images together. This process ussually takes 0.5seconds for each image to be stitched together, i would like to optimise this so that the images are stitched together at a faster rate.

So, at the moment i have a 2 arrays each containing 800 images, i also have a function called stitch_images which processes each image set to be stitched together. However, for this function im using a while loop to go through each image and stitch it to its corresponding image - this seems to be causing me issues as the while loop is blocking the process. I'm also using 2 shared global variables which contain the images.

Theoretically what i would like to achieve is 4 processes, each process process takes a set of image and works on it --> effectively reducing the computational time by 1/4th.

my question is, how would i go about achieving this? i understand that there are multiple different ways of multiprocessing in python such as threading, multiprocess, queues. which would be the best option for me? if there is an easy way to implement this would anyone have any example code for this?

this is my current set up:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import cv2

# Global variables:
frames_1 = []
frames_2 = []
panorama = []


# converting the video into frames for individual image processing
def convert_video_to_frames():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("Sample_video_1.mp4")
    ret = True
    while ret:
        ret, img = cap.read()  # read one frame from the 'capture' object; img is (H, W, C)
        if ret:
            frames_1.append(img)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("Sample_video_2.mp4")
    ret = True
    while ret:
        ret, img = cap.read()  # read one frame from the 'capture' object; img is (H, W, C)
        if ret:
            frames_2.append(img)

    return frames_1, frames_2


#converting final output images back to video
def convert_frames_to_video():
    print("now creating stitched image video")
    height, width, layers = panorama[0].shape
    size = (width, height)
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 15, size)
    for i in range(len(panorama)):
        out.write(panorama[i])
    out.release()


def stitch_images():
    print("image processing starting...")
    stitcher = cv2.Stitcher_create(cv2.STITCHER_PANORAMA)
    while len(frames_1) != 0:
        status, result = stitcher.stitch((frames_1.pop(0), frames_2.pop(0)))
        if status == 0:  # pass
            panorama.append(result)
        else:
            print("image stitching failed")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    convert_video_to_frames()  # dummy function

    start = time.perf_counter()
    stitch_images()
    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'finished in {round(finish - start, 2)} seconds(s)')

    print("now converting images to video...")
    convert_frames_to_video()
```

Also, i've attempted at using multiprocessing and adding locks to achieve this but adding:

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=stitch_images)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=stitch_images)
    
p1.start()
p2.start()
    
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

but when i run this it seems to skip the while loop all together?

Comment: In a panorama, adding a new image requires access to the previous image so it can find the stitch points.  It's not clear to me that process can be parallelized.

Comment: im not sure i understand, the panorama array is just the output array, its just an empty array that will be holding all of the stitched images together. The images are grabbed from frames_1 and frames_2, stitched and added to an empty array thats called panorama.

Comment: You need the output products in a particular order, right?  One of the issues with multiprocessing is that the finish order is not guaranteed.

Comment: i do need the outputs in order, but wouldn't i be able to use a lock to verify that they are in order?

Comment: Then you lose all the benefits of multiprocessing.